# Get data for display purpose only in MVC 5, EF 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My model class is like this

```
public class Appointment
{
    public int AppointmentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ProcedureID { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public virtual Procedure Procedure { get; set; }
}
```

And inside my controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.ProcedureID = new SelectList(db.Procedures, "ProcedureID", "ViCode");
    return View();
}
```

In view

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProcedureID", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This way I could show all procedures, But how could I show all Departments, I don't want to add a field called `DepartmentID` inside the model because it will act as a foreign key in the table then, which I do not want. My usage with Departments is for show only purpose. How could I achieve this?

Comment: You're going to have problems with that DropDownList code, you're using the same name in your ViewBag (ProcedureID) as your Model, but they're different types (one is a SelectList, the other an Int)  When you post back data, you're going to get problems.

Comment: @StephenMuecke isn't there any other way than view model?

Comment: Using a view model will solve the issue Erik raised plus give you lots of other benefits (e.g. validation attributes) but if you not binding to anything, you could always just create a dropownlist based on a ViewBag property - `ViewBag.NotBoundProperty = new SelectList(..);` and `@Html.DropDownList("NotBoundProperty" ...)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have not completely understood your comment. Can you add it as an answer here with more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [ViewModel](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3). The View Model is a class you make specifically to send data from the controller to the View. It is not the entity you use in Entity framework. It can contain entities, lists of entities, SelectList objects and any combinations of things you need. It also has the benefit of being statically typed (unlike the ViewBag)

```
public class CreateViewModel
{
    public SelectList Producers {get; set;}
    public List<Department> Departments {get; set;}
    public int SelectedProducerID {get; set;}
}
```

In the Controller

```
var model = new CreateViewModel
            {
               Producers = new SelectList(db.Procedures, "ProcedureID", "ViCode");
               Departments = db.Departments.ToList()
            }

return View(model);
```

In the View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedProducerID, Model.Producers, ...)
```

I don't know how you want to display the departments but you can just loop through them and display them in the html. I have not tested the code.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample code on how achieve this here

Comment: One more question. Is there any specific folder where I need to create viewmodel? like in Model folder or something else? And Is there any naming convention for it?

Comment: And in controller inside which action I need to write your code?

Comment: Well in Create I guess. Whatever action you are asking for. The POST version of create accepts a CreateViewModel as an argument. There is no specific folder for ViewModels. Either make a ViewModels folder or use Models.

Answer (score 2):

try like this , pure html + Razor suntax

```
<select name="departments">
  @for (var i = 0; i < model.Departments ; i++){

    <option>@(model.Departments[i])</option>
  }
</select>
```